# gwt- frame respond url change

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using a `Frame` (see code) in my gwt app.
The problem is that my frame doesn't respond on url (passed as a String) changes.
My app starts with an empty frame (variable frameURL = "") and then I would like to let a random user decide which url is next.

Here some code:

```
public class MyApp extends Composite {

    private static MyAppUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(MyAppUiBinder.class);

    public static String frameURL = "";

    @UiField
    Frame frame;

    interface MyAppUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyApp> {
    }

    public MyApp() {

        this.frame = new Frame();
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this)); 
        frame.setUrl(getUrl());
    }       
        public void setUrl(String url){
            MyApp.frameURL = url;
        }

        public String getUrl(){
            return frameURL;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Frame#setUrl()`:

```
public void setUrl(String url) {
  frame.setUrl(url);
}
```